# what entity should be defined for 4 digit Pin

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-home

For Google Home, I have a pin Intent which takes 4 digit pin for a banking application.

I defined its entity type to "number sequence" but that doesn't seem to work for specific sequences. Interestingly whenever there is 2 & 1 inbetween (for eg 2212,3212, 4212.. etc) it interprets it as 2 to 1/2, 3 to 1/2 and so on.

What is the best way to define pin so as to get 2212 when I say 2212

Comment: Hi. I actually validated this as I pretty much have the same requirement for mine and for "most cases" this works. Could you provide an example of your utterance?

Comment: Yeh it works. But fails for a specific pattern where 2&1 are in middle. Define a pin intent and utterence as "Pin" and give it a entity as number sequence and test the same in diagflow using Mic. Check the values 2212,3212,4212,5212,6212,7212,8212,9212

Comment: I got a reply from DiagFlow saying this is expected behavior and you should say five thousand two hundred and twelve (5212)for it to recognize. Pretty weird behavior